# arranging dataframe with split and replace, having issues with backslashes

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a DataFrame that looks like this where there are two rows and one column.

```
df = ['\n1\nSPY\n20,996,893\n7,560,307\n13,436,586\n1.78\n']
```

I want to have the DataFrame to be split by the backslash and to be created as a new column while also removing the "n". I have tried `df.replace('n','')` to remove the "n" but nothing will happen.

I would like it to look like this,

```
    0
0   1
1   SPY
2   20996893
3   7560307
4   13436586
5   1.78
```

The same will happen when I try to split the columns. Any ideas?

Comment: can you post your expected output

Comment: @deadshot just added example

Comment: do you want split one row as multiple rows? and how the output looks if the dataframe has more than one row?

Comment: I would ideally like it like a transposed version of the example I put in above

Comment: ``pd.DataFrame(df[0].strip().splitlines())`` ?

Comment: `df2 = df[0].str.strip().str.split('\n', expand=True).T`

Comment: hi there, did you try my solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
df = ['\n1\nSPY\n20,996,893\n7,560,307\n13,436,586\n1.78\n']
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df = df.str.strip().str.split('\n').explode().reindex()
```

The split creates a list inside each cell (when the dataframe has more rows). And explode splits that list into rows, repeating the index and any other columns the dataframe might have. Then we use reindex to reset it to DefaultIndex (i.e. 0 to n-1)

*Edit*

As per your comment. If what you want is not to include more rows but split into columns.

```
df = df.str.strip().str.split('\n', expand=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
l =  ['\n1\nSPY\n20,996,893\n7,560,307\n13,436,586\n1.78\n']
s = pd.Series(l)    
print(s.str.strip('\n').str.split('\n', expand=True).T)
```

Output:

```
            0
0           1
1         SPY
2  20,996,893
3   7,560,307
4  13,436,586
5        1.78
```